# Why is hsqldb the owner of my directory?

Tags: fedora, nfs, mount

I am evaluating Fedora 11. I mounted a NFS share from a NAS and I noticed that hsqldb is listed as both the owner and group for the directory I mounted the NFS share to. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the uids/gids on the nfs server don't match those on the client.  When they don't, what your describing is the usual result.

Look at the uid of the file on the NFS server and then on the client.  Does uid 96 (taken from you comment) belong to the same user on both server and client?

Answer (score 1):

Check on your host user id and group id for user "hsqldb" (cat /etc/password; cat /etc/group).
Then list the mounted share with

> ls -n -d mnt-point

You should see the same UID+GID. Some process has written to your NAS and has set UID+GID to the same values as you have in your user database.

HTH.

Comment: ls -n shows an id of 96 for both user and group. This matches up with the hsqldb user from /etc/group

Comment: There's no need for `cat /etc/passwd`. There's a better way: `id hsqldb`.